# Coordinates of Leaflet.Draw rectangle

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.draw

Is it possible to get the coordinates of the rectangle on mouseClick, so I have all the corners of the rectangle?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

See event object (http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#event-objects):

```
var map = L.map('map').setView([53.902257, 27.561640], 13);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);

var bounds = [[53.912257, 27.581640], [53.902257, 27.561640]];

var rect = L.rectangle(bounds, {color: 'blue', weight: 1}).on('click', function (e) {
    // There event is event object
    // there e.type === 'click'
    // there e.lanlng === L.LatLng on map
    // there e.target.getLatLngs() - your rectangle coordinates
    // but e.target !== rect
    console.info(e);
}).addTo(map);
```

Use `e.target.getLatLngs()`.

Comment: Please show the bounds semantic, my input is `{ne:{lat: -23.5601806640625lon: -46.64794921875}, sw:{lat: -23.565673828125,lon: -46.658935546875}}`.

Comment: Thank you. This helped me years later :)

Comment: A nice little snippet when I was trying some `mapBounds.extend()`. Just draw a different box for each new set of bounds  & see how the fit to the map. Thanks, +1

Answer (score 14):

[`Leaflet.draw` plugin](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.draw) uses standard [Leaflet's L.Rectangle](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#rectangle).

Leaflet's rectangle extends [Polygon](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polygon). Polygon extends [Polyline](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#polyline).

Therefore, in order to get the coordinates of the Leaflet.draw's rectangle you can use Polyline's method `getLatLngs()` that returns an array of the points in the path.

**Example:**

```
var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
map.addLayer(drawnItems);

map.on('draw:created', function (e) {

    var type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;

    if (type === 'rectangle') {
        layer.on('mouseover', function() {
            alert(layer.getLatLngs());    
        });
    }

    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```

Comment: Do you know why layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates will add another coordinate.

Comment: @Spir: layer.getLatLngs() will return a LatLng-array of an unclosed polygon. layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates will return a LngLat-array of a CLOSED polygon. (the last point is the first point)

Comment: Also, layer.getLatLngs() won't be available if the shape is a circle. A circle will instead have layer.getLatLng(), but ToGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates is always there.

Answer (score 1):

```
map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (e) {

    var layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);

    console.log(layer.getLatLngs())

});
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be noted that e.layerType contains the shape-type that is being created. 
Methods like getLatLngs and getLatLng are specific to the shapetype.

These are the different types allowed in layer according to the typescript definition file

```
Circle | CircleMarker | Marker | Polygon | Polyline | Rectangle;
```

And the possible values for e.layerType are (according to the typescript definition file)

```
circle, marker, polygon, polyline, rectangle
```

So you can always get the coordinates with e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates. 
But you need to switch between the e.layerType-s, because the circle geojson does not contain the radius, you need to get it with getRadius.
Further note, that getLatLngs returns a **LatLng**-array of an **UN**closed polygon, while toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates returns a **closed** polygon with coordinates as **LngLat**-arrray.

```
// console.log((<any>e.layer).getLatLngs()); // polyline
// console.log((<any>e.layer).getLatLng()); // circle
// mind the s at the end of the function...


map.on('draw:created', function(e:L.DrawEvents.Created) 
{
    console.log('On draw:created', e.target);
    console.log(e.type, e);


    console.log(e.layerType);
    // console.log((<any>e.layer).getLatLngs()); // polyline
    // console.log((<any>e.layer).getLatLng()); // circle

    // e.layerType // polygon, circle, etc. 

    // polygon 
    // e.layer.getLatLngs()

    // circle
    // e.layer.getLatLng()
    // e.layer.getRadius()


    // e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.type // is point if circle 
    // e.layer.toGeoJSON().geometry.coordinates

    let type = e.layerType,
        layer = e.layer;
    drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
});
```